# How to perform DAST on D365 ERP On Prem application using Veracode?

Tags: security, erp, veracode, devsecops

How to perform DAST on D365 ERP On Prem application using Veracode?

We are planning to implement Veracode for performing DAST on D365 ERP on Prem application.